# Get indirect relationships with nodes and relationship direction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get all the nodes and relationships in a path in following format: node1, node2, relationship-type, relationship-direction.

I tried getting path using this query. From this I can get nodes and relationships. But cannot get the directions of relationships.

```
MATCH path = (e1:Entity)-[rel*1..4]-(e2:Entity)
WHERE e1._id = "222" AND  e2._id = "777"
RETURN path
```

I want the result to be similar to output of the following query which returns direct relationships.

```
MATCH (e1:Entity) WHERE e1._id = "222"
MATCH (e2:Entity) WHERE e2._id = "333"
MATCH (e1)-[rel]-(e2)
RETURN e1, e2, type(rel), (startNode(rel) = e1) as isOut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but I could not find a simple solution. So let's go with the complicated one.

First, create an example graph:

```
CREATE
  (a:Entity {name: 'a'}),
  (b:Entity {name: 'b'}),
  (c:Entity {name: 'c'}),
  (d:Entity {name: 'd'}),
  (e:Entity {name: 'e'}),
  (a)-[:REL {name: 'r1'}]->(b)
    <-[:REL {name: 'r2'}]-(c)
     -[:REL {name: 'r3'}]->(d)
     -[:REL {name: 'r4'}]->(e)
```

[image]

Use this query:

```
MATCH (e1 {name: 'a'})-[rels*1..4]-(e2 {name: 'e'})
WITH e1, e2, rels,
  extract(rel IN rels | startNode(rel)) AS startNodes,
  extract(rel IN rels | endNode(rel)) AS endNodes,
  range(1, size(rels)-1) AS indexes
WITH e1, e2, rels, startNodes, endNodes, indexes, startNodes[0] AS start
UNWIND indexes AS i
WITH e1, e2,
  e1 = start as isOutFirst, 
  (endNodes[i-1] = startNodes[i] OR
   startNodes[i-1] = startNodes[i]) AS isOut
WITH e1, e2, isOutFirst, collect(isOut) AS isOuts
RETURN e1, e2, [isOutFirst] + isOuts AS isOuts
```

The result is:

```
╒═════════╤═════════╤═════════════════════════╕
│e1       │e2       │isOuts                   │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│{name: a}│{name: e}│[true, false, true, true]│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

The main ideas are the following:

1. We get the start and end node for each relationship using the [`extract`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-extract) method.
2. We use the [`range`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-range) function and [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-unwind) to generate a list of indexes and "iterate" on the lists.
3. The *i.* relationship is outgoing (`isOut`) if it starts from any node of the previous (*i-1.*) relationship.
4. The 0. relationship has no previous relationship, hence we treat it separately (`isOutFirst`).
5. We collect the `isOut` values to an `isOuts` list.
6. We combine the `isOutFirst` variable and the `isOuts` list to a single list.

You can `UNWIND` the results and add the corresponding relationship types:

```
MATCH (e1 {name: 'a'})-[rels*1..4]-(e2 {name: 'e'})
WITH e1, e2, rels,
  extract(rel IN rels | startNode(rel)) AS startNodes,
  extract(rel IN rels | endNode(rel)) AS endNodes,
  range(1, size(rels)-1) AS indexes
WITH e1, e2, rels, startNodes, endNodes, indexes, startNodes[0] AS start
UNWIND indexes AS i
WITH e1, e2, rels,
  e1 = start as isOutFirst, 
  (endNodes[i-1] = startNodes[i] OR
   startNodes[i-1] = startNodes[i]) AS isOut
WITH e1, e2, rels, isOutFirst, collect(isOut) AS isOuts
WITH e1, e2, rels, 
  [isOutFirst] + isOuts AS isOuts, 
  range(0, size(rels)-1) AS indexes2
UNWIND indexes2 AS i
RETURN e1, e2, type(rels[i]) AS relType, isOuts[i] AS isOut
```

This results in:

```
╒═════════╤═════════╤═══════╤═════╕
│e1       │e2       │relType│isOut│
╞═════════╪═════════╪═══════╪═════╡
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │true │
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────┤
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │false│
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────┤
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │true │
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────┤
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │true │
└─────────┴─────────┴───────┴─────┘
```

**Update:** you can use the direction to extract the nodes in the correct order from the path:

```
MATCH (e1 {name: 'a'})-[rels*1..4]-(e2 {name: 'e'})
WITH e1, e2, rels,
  extract(rel IN rels | startNode(rel)) AS startNodes,
  extract(rel IN rels | endNode(rel)) AS endNodes,
  range(1, size(rels)-1) AS indexes
WITH e1, e2, rels, startNodes, endNodes, indexes, startNodes[0] AS start
UNWIND indexes AS i
WITH e1, e2, rels,
  e1 = start as isOutFirst, 
  (endNodes[i-1] = startNodes[i] OR
   startNodes[i-1] = startNodes[i]) AS isOut
WITH e1, e2, rels, isOutFirst, collect(isOut) AS isOuts
WITH e1, e2, rels, 
  [isOutFirst] + isOuts AS isOuts, 
  range(0, size(rels)-1) AS indexes2
UNWIND indexes2 AS i
RETURN e1, e2, type(rels[i]) AS relType,
  CASE isOuts[i]
    WHEN true THEN startNode(rels[i])
    ELSE endNode(rels[i])
  END AS node1,
  CASE isOuts[i]
    WHEN true THEN endNode(rels[i])
    ELSE startNode(rels[i])
  END AS node2
```

This results in:

```
╒═════════╤═════════╤═══════╤═════════╤═════════╕
│e1       │e2       │relType│node1    │node2    │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │{name: a}│{name: b}│
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │{name: b}│{name: c}│
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │{name: c}│{name: d}│
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│{name: a}│{name: e}│REL    │{name: d}│{name: e}│
└─────────┴─────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

**Limitations:** the solutions above might not work if there is a 2-length circle in the graph, e.g. for a graph `(a)<-[r1]-(b)<-[r2]-(a)`, they incorrectly mark `(b)<-[r2]-(a)` as outgoing for one of the paths.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Seems like this is very complex in neo4j. Instead of getting e1 and e2 as starting and ending nodes, can I get them as from and to nodes of relevant relationships ? for example a,b,REL,true    b,c,REL,false     c,d,REL,true      d,e, REL, true

Comment: Sure - I extended the answer with a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Prasad19sara if the answer provides a solution for your question, please don't forget to mark it as "accepted". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my question was not clear.Sorry for that. Based on the previous answer I was able to get the relationships with nodes as follows for my use-case. In here I do not need isOut column since start and end nodes are there.

`MATCH (e1 {_id: '222'})-[rels*1..4]-(e2 {_id: '777'})
WITH range(0, size(rels)-1) AS indexes,rels
UNWIND indexes AS i
RETURN startNode( rels[i]), type(rels[i]),endNode( rels[i])`

Comment: No problem, glad that you found a simple solution for you use case. Note however, that in the result of your query, the start and end nodes of the relationships will be determined for each relationship individually (and not based on the path). So, for a path `(a)-[:REL1]->(b)<-[:REL2]-(c)`, you will get the following rows: `a, REL1, b` and `c, REL2, b`, instead of `a, REL1, b` and `b, REL2, c`.

Comment: A small tip: use indentation of 4 spaces for code blocks instead of backticks. (There is a button in the editor which does this, or just use `Ctrl` + `K`.)